# Extracting text with iTextSharp throws an InvalidCastException

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm currently extracting text from a PDF file with iTextSharp.

With dozens of PDFs it works fine however 2 of the PDFs throws an invalid cast exceptio Stacktrace at [1].

The code which throws this exception is the following (the exception throws at GetTextFromPage):

```
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(byteArray);
        PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
```

Some additional notes:

- The Preflight Syntax check in Adobe Acrobat doesn't find any errors.
- A sample PDF which generates this error is located at: http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/DisparityModel (The paper (Adobe Acrobat PDF, 6.69 MB). )
- I tried already the LocationTextExtractionStrategy - same error.

How can I check the PDF file if it is corrupt, beside the Preflight? Or where does this error come from?

[1]

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfLiteral' to type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfString'.
  Source=itextsharp
  StackTrace:
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.DocumentFont.FillMetrics(Byte[] touni, IntHashtable widths, Int32 dw)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.DocumentFont.ProcessType0(PdfDictionary font)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.DocumentFont.Init()
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.DocumentFont..ctor(PRIndirectReference refFont)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.CMapAwareDocumentFont..ctor(PRIndirectReference refFont)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.GetFont(PRIndirectReference ind)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.SetTextFont.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.FormXObjectDoHandler.HandleXObject(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfStream stream, PdfIndirectReference refi)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.DisplayXObject(PdfName xobjectName)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.Do.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.ProcessContent[E](Int32 pageNumber, E renderListener)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfReader reader, Int32 pageNumber, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy)
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in e:\foobar\projects\AnalyzePDF\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 24
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: If you can't share the PDFs, we can't reproduce the error. If we can't reproduce the error, we can't investigate. Which version of iTextSharp are you using (the latest is 5.5.3). Are you a customer? If so, we have NDAs in place to deal with sensitive documents.

Comment: I'm using the latest iTextSharp yes. No I'm not a customer. Can you access the PDF file on this site: http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/DisparityModel (The paper (Adobe Acrobat PDF, 6.69 MB).
) ?

Comment: Not right away. I'm still working through my mails and I have a couple of meetings. I probably won't have time to look at this until after JavaOne.

Comment: No problem. I was just wondering as this exact cast wasn't covered in any other Stack-overflow questions.

Comment: iText parses syntax to find *specific* PDF objects (numbers, names, strings, dictionaries, arrays,...). When it detects something that doesn't fit any of the PDF objects defined in the spec, it creates a `PdfLiteral` object. In your case, your PDF has a unidentifiable object where a `PdfString` is expected. Other tools ignore such objects. iText throws an exception. Or that's what I assume (I didn't look at the PDF yet).

Comment: Interesting. I understand why Adobe allows opening/copying corrupted PDFs. But the syntax check should theoretically check for such non defined objects? Are there other checks where these objects are checked? Or is there a switch to just ignore non defined objects?

Comment: I can produce a couple of PDFs that pass Adobe's Preflight, but that are totally wrong ;-) I don't know if there are checks available. Maybe iText is just too strict... It should be investigated...

Comment: Do you have anything more than the above stack dump? Even the page number would help. The only thing that I can find by eye inspecting a >64,000 lines dump is an array of `/Widths` that contain floating point numbers -- in most cases, these are integers (but I don't think Bruno missed this).

Comment: How can I provide you more information? The function doesn't give me much more than the stacktrace. You can take the PDF file from the comments and the code and it will give you the same error. The linked PDF file has 8 pages. And afaik Bruno didn't yet check the file.

Comment: I'm not using iText, I wrote my own PDF checker. You are printing the page contents in a loop, so you may get *some* relevant output. That is, unless it already crashes while initializing the PDF?

Comment: The print doesn't actually matter. It crashes already during reading the first page. I've updated the code in the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document in question contains a font with the following **ToUnicode** map:

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource
begin
12 dict
begin
/CIDSystemInfo <</Ordering (UCS) /Registry (Adobe) /Supplement 0 >> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <ffffffffffffffff> endcodespacerange
20 beginbfchar
<0003> <0020> <0012> <0043> <0018> <0044> <0045> <004e> <0059> <0051> <005e> <0053> <0102> <0061> <0110> <0063> <011a> <0064> <011e> <0065> <015d> <0069> <0175> <006d> <0176> <006e> <017d> <006f> <01ffffff89> <0070> <01ffffff8c> <0072> <01ffffff90> <0073> <01ffffff9a> <0074> <01ffffffb5> <0075> <01ffffffc7> <0079> endbfchar
100 beginbfchar
<01ffffffcc> <007a> endcmap
CMapName
currentdict
/CMap defineresource
pop
end
end
ý
```

The section where iText(Sharp) stumbles is:

```
100 beginbfchar
<01ffffffcc> <007a> endcmap
```

i.e. a section started by `beginbfchar` and ended by the non-matching `endcmap`.

I think a section started by `beginbfchar` always has to end in `endbfchar`.

The font in question is a *Calibri* subset composite font. It is used in the form xobject used as **Fm0** on the first page. That xobject has a dictionary entry

```
/PTEX.FileName (C:/MyFiles/Publications/DisparityMetric/Figures/Teaser.pdf)
```

so it probably has been copied from that Teaser.pdf file.

Comment: I'll look into this and report back. Thank you for the info.

Comment: You were right, that Calibri font produced that error. Thanks again. Now out of curiosity, is this a minor bug in iText or in the Calibri font :-) ?

Comment: I think section starts and ends must match here. So the embedded subset font is the problem. Most likely the issue is not in the original font but instead has been introduced by the subset generator.