# Extract text using iTextSharp with different PDF page labels

Tags: pdf, itext, text-extraction

I am trying to extract text from PDF using iTextSharp but I get null reference error while trying to call **GetTextFromPage**:

[image: Calling GetTextFromPage]

[image: Exception thrown]

My guess would be that iTextSharp somehow interprets page label incorrectly as it is indeed strange:

[image: Strange page label]

Or is it due danish letters in the text?

[image: Danish letters]

However, I am able to extract text from different languages.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** The problem could also be used fonts and their *custom* encoding:

[image]

Comment: According to your image the issue occurs while initializing a font object. A `NullReferenceException` here usually indicates that there is an error in the PDF itself. For further analysis please share the document in question or another one with the same internal detail causing the issue.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am unable to share the file due to GDPR. However, I think the problem could be in the fonts. In the PDF it says that 2 out of 4 used fonts has this "Custom" encoding. I found another thread regarding it but in this case I am also unable to change fonts as these PDFs are being provided by third party. [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010284/extracting-text-with-itextsharp-throws-an-invalidcastexception+)

Comment: The stack trace of that "similar issue" is completely different. I'm sorry, without *the document in question or another one with the same internal detail causing the issue* I cannot analyze any further.

Comment: But is there a way to ignore fonts somehow?

Comment: The fonts (more exactly: the PDF font objects, not necessarily font programs embedded therein) contain information on the encoding of text. If you ignore the fonts, text extraction usually returns something like letter salad, in particular in case of custom font encodings...

Comment: @programmer3000 Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @http203 Hi! Yes, unfortunately I had to use another library..